# what is this return method called?

Tags: java, c++

I've come apon this syntax a few times in programming books and other open source programs I've been looking at.

```
return am == null ? "": (String) am.get();
```

or

```
return Level != 0 ? String.format("({0})", Level) : "";
```

What is this pattern called? I've tried searching for the `value ? value : value;` type pattern hoping it would come up both here and on google, but so far no luck. I think I know what it's doing but I would love to know what to call it to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, i've only seen it in return statements so far, never thought of it as used outside of that. I find it strange someone would ask for it as a `? :`. the values seem integral to figuring it out. There should be a way to make it easier to find these multiples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a "ternary operator," also known as a "conditional operator": `condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`.

To my knowledge there's no special name for it when it's used in a `return` statement.

Comment: The operator even has a name: It's called the *conditional operator*.